# What does this answer to the question below imply?

Tags: word-meaning

> Do you like talking and meeting with people in your neighborhood?
>
> **I'm not getting accustomed to people.**

Could you paraphrase the answer in simple English?

Comment: Can you cite a source for this? Honestly, the answer does not actually answer the question.

Comment: As written, it implies: I have lived alone for all my life and cannot get used to being around people in general, not just the new people within this neighborhood.  The way people is used here is as a label for all humans in general and I'm pretty sure this is not what was meant.  Some further explanation would really help please.

Answer (score 1):

As @Catija said, the answer as written does not follow the situation. Perhaps you mean:

> I'm not **accustomed to** talking to people.

or

> I'm **not accustomed** to meeting people.

You can also use *used to*, or in a general sense "comfortable", in place of "accustomed to":

> I'm not **used to** talking to people.
>   I'm not **comfortable** talking to people.